# How to open sql .csv file?

Tags: sql, excel, csv

Using a `SELECT` query in sql I got results with many rows and columns. It display nicely by rows and columns, none of them mixed up.

I right click at the top left corner and save as .csv. Then I open this file using Excel and I see many fields were mixed or the words, values go to the wrong columns.

Do you know how is the right way to save the result or how is the right way to view this .csv file from sql ?

Thank you.

Update as requested: I using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. 
Some Rows in my results table before saving in csv file: (contains few columns here)

```
Company Pte Ltd Advanced Materials Technologies Pte Ltd. produces precision metal and ceramic parts. It offers metal hinges, metal packages, intricate cylinders, and valve components; latches and counterweights for hard disk drives;
```

Or row with two columns (first is company name, second is company's characteristic):

```
ABC PTE LTD  •Project Management&#x0D;  •Precision Mould Design and Fabrication&#x0D;  •Multi Colours/Materials Moulding&#x0D;  •Over Moulding&#x0D;  •Extreme Thin Wall Compression Moulding&#x0D;  •Micro Moulding&#x0D;
```

I tried to click at the top left corner of the result table to select all, then right click and chose "copy with header" then past to excel. But here is some problems:
In SSMS I see result clearly in this data:

```
XYZ Ltd <p>  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="780">  <tbody>  <tr>  <td valign="top" width="140">  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="140" height="628">  <tbody>  <tr>  <td height="628" valign="top" width="140">  <p></p></td></tr></tbody></table></td>  <td valign="top" width="500">  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="500" align="center" height="619">  <tbody>  <tr>  <td height="619" width="500">  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><b><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 12pt">About Us</span></font></b></p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px">&nbsp;</p><img src="http://www.shaofook.com/images/01.jpg" width="240" height="180"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="http://www.shaofook.com/images/02.jpg" width="240" height="180">   <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><strong><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt"><br />Shao Fook Engineering </span></font></strong><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt"><b>Pte Ltd </b>was established in March 1989 as a partnership offering contract services for industrial steel fabrication, installation of equipment for oil refineries, petrochemical, industrial plants, turnkey construction project works for factory expansion and most recently the pharmaceutical industry.</span></font></p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px">&nbsp;</p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt">We undertake project work from laydown to complete installation of Packaged equipment such as Pipe Rack Structures, Equipment Structures, Flare Stack Structure, Fired Heaters, HRSG, Boilers, Incinerators, Bio-treaters, Cooling Tower as well as Modular equipment such as Compressors, Pumps, Reactors, Silos, Towers, Exchanges, Loading Arms and quick turn around plant maintenance &nbsp;projects.</span></font></p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt"></span></font>&nbsp;</p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt">We also perform Laser Alignment of Rotating Equipment.</span></font></p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px">&nbsp;</p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt">We have clocked more than 5 million man-hours and handled more than 100,000 Ton of Steel Structure and 50,000 Ton of equipment within customer's budget and schedule. We diligently adhere to safety procedure outlined in our established Work Procedure, Method Statement and Job Safety Analysis.</span></font></p></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table>  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="780">  <tbody>  <tr>  <td valign="top" width="140">  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="140" height="628">  <tbody>  <tr>  <td height="628" valign="top" width="140">  <p></p></td></tr></tbody></table></td>  <td valign="top" width="500">  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="500" align="center" height="619">  <tbody>  <tr>  <td height="619" width="500">  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><b><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 12pt">About Us</span></font></b></p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px">&nbsp;</p><img src="http://www.shaofook.com/images/01.jpg" width="240" height="180"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="http://www.shaofook.com/images/02.jpg" width="240" height="180">   <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><strong><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt"><br />Shao Fook Engineering </span></font></strong><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt"><b>Pte Ltd </b>was established in March 1989 as a partnership offering contract services for industrial steel fabrication, installation of equipment for oil refineries, petrochemical, industrial plants, turnkey construction project works for factory expansion and most recently the pharmaceutical industry.</span></font></p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px">&nbsp;</p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt">We undertake project work from laydown to complete installation of Packaged equipment such as Pipe Rack Structures, Equipment Structures, Flare Stack Structure, Fired Heaters, HRSG, Boilers, Incinerators, Bio-treaters, Cooling Tower as well as Modular equipment such as Compressors, Pumps, Reactors, Silos, Towers, Exchanges, Loading Arms and quick turn around plant maintenance &nbsp;projects.</span></font></p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt"></span></font>&nbsp;</p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt">We also perform Laser Alignment of Rotating Equipment.</span></font></p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px">&nbsp;</p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt">We have clocked more than 5 million man-hours and handled more than 100,000 Ton of Steel Structure and 50,000 Ton of equipment within customer's budget and schedule. We diligently adhere to safety procedure outlined in our established Work Procedure, Method Statement and Job Safety Analysis.</span></font></p></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table><font color="#333333"><strong><font size="2">Shao Fook Engineering </font></strong><font face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt"><strong>Pte Ltd </strong>was established in March 1989 as a partnership offering contract services for industrial steel fabrication, installation of equipment for oil refineries, petrochemical, industrial plants, turnkey construction project works for factory expansion and most recently the pharmaceutical industry.</span></font></font></p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px">&nbsp;</p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt">We undertake project work from laydown to complete installation of Packaged equipment such as Pipe Rack Structures, Equipment Structures, Flare Stack Structure, Fired Heaters, HRSG, Boilers, Incinerators, Bio-treaters, Cooling Tower as well as Modular equipment such as Compressors, Pumps, Reactors, Silos, Towers, Exchanges, Loading Arms and quick turn around plant maintenance &nbsp;projects.</span></font></p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt"></span></font>&nbsp;</p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt">We also perform Laser Alignment of Rotating Equipment.</span></font></p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px">&nbsp;</p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt">We have clocked more than 5 million man-hours and handled more than 100,000 Ton of Steel Structure and 50,000 Ton of equipment within customer's budget and schedule. We diligently adhere to safety procedure outlined in our established Work Procedure, Method Statement and Job Safety Analysis.</span></font></p>   - Heavy Lifting & Logistic Services    - Laser Alignment and Leveling of Rotating Equipment    - Industrial Fabrication Work & Plant Maintenance    - Equipment Installation for Factories & Industrial Plants    - Construction Works - Mechanical (Major), Civil, Electrical    - Conveyance & Installation of Material Handling & Production   Machines  - Heavy Lifting & Logistic Services    - Laser Alignment and Leveling of Rotating Equipment    - Industrial Fabrication Work & Plant Maintenance    - Equipment Installation for Factories & Industrial Plants    - Construction Works - Mechanical (Major), Civil, Electrical    - Conveyance & Installation of Material Handling & Production   Machines
```

But when I paste in excel I will get this:

```
XYZ Ltd <p>  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="780">  <tbody>  <tr>  <td valign="top" width="140">  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="140" height="628">  <tbody>  <tr>  <td height="628" valign="top" width="140">  <p></p></td></tr></tbody></table></td>  <td valign="top" width="500">  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="500" align="center" height="619">  <tbody>  <tr>  <td height="619" width="500">  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><b><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 12pt">About Us</span></font></b></p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px">&nbsp;</p><img src="http://www.shaofook.com/images/01.jpg" width="240" height="180"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="http://www.shaofook.com/images/02.jpg" width="240" height="180">   <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><strong><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt"><br />Shao Fook Engineering </span></font></strong><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt"><b>Pte Ltd </b>was established in March 1989 as a partnership offering contract services for industrial steel fabrication, installation of equipment for oil refineries, petrochemical, industrial plants, turnkey construction project works for factory expansion and most recently the pharmaceutical industry.</span></font></p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px">&nbsp;</p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt">We undertake project work from laydown to complete installation of Packaged equipment such as Pipe Rack Structures, Equipment Structures, Flare Stack Structure, Fired Heaters, HRSG, Boilers, Incinerators, Bio-treaters, Cooling Tower as well as Modular equipment such as Compressors, Pumps, Reactors, Silos, Towers, Exchanges, Loading Arms and quick turn around plant maintenance &nbsp;projects.</span></font></p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt"></span></font>&nbsp;</p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt">We also perform Laser Alignment of Rotating Equipment.</span></font></p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px">&nbsp;</p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt">We have clocked more than 5 million man-hours and handled more than 100,000 Ton of Steel Structure and 50,000 Ton of equipment within customer's budget and schedule. We diligently adhere to safety procedure outlined in our established Work Procedure, Method Statement and Job Safety Analysis.</span></font></p></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table>  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="780">  <tbody>  <tr>  <td valign="top" width="140">  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="140" height="628">  <tbody>  <tr>  <td height="628" valign="top" width="140">  <p></p></td></tr></tbody></table></td>  <td valign="top" width="500">  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="500" align="center" height="619">  <tbody>  <tr>  <td height="619" width="500">  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><b><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 12pt">About Us</span></font></b></p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px">&nbsp;</p><img src="http://www.shaofook.com/images/01.jpg" width="240" height="180"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="http://www.shaofook.com/images/02.jpg" width="240" height="180">   <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><strong><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt"><br />Shao Fook Engineering </span></font></strong><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt"><b>Pte Ltd </b>was established in March 1989 as a partnership offering contract services for industrial steel fabrication, installation of equipment for oil refineries, petrochemical, industrial plants, turnkey construction project works for factory expansion and most recently the pharmaceutical industry.</span></font></p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px">&nbsp;</p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt">We undertake project work from laydown to complete installation of Packaged equipment such as Pipe Rack Structures, Equipment Structures, Flare Stack Structure, Fired Heaters, HRSG, Boilers, Incinerators, Bio-treaters, Cooling Tower as well as Modular equipment such as Compressors, Pumps, Reactors, Silos, Towers, Exchanges, Loading Arms and quick turn around plant maintenance &nbsp;projects.</span></font></p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt"></span></font>&nbsp;</p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt">We also perform Laser Alignment of Rotating Equipment.</span></font></p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px">&nbsp;</p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt">We have clocked more than 5 million man-hours and handled more than 100,000 Ton of Steel Structure and 50,000 Ton of equipment within customer's budget and schedule. We diligently adhere to safety procedure outlined in our established Work Procedure, Method Statement and Job Safety Analysis.</span></font></p></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table><font color="#333333"><strong><font size="2">Shao Fook Engineering </font></strong><font face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt"><strong>Pte Ltd </strong>was established in March 1989 as a partnership offering contract services for industrial steel fabrication, installation of equipment for oil refineries, petrochemical, industrial plants, turnkey construction project works for factory expansion and most recently the pharmaceutical industry.</span></font></font></p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px">&nbsp;</p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt">We undertake project work from laydown to complete installation of Packaged equipment such as Pipe Rack Structures, Equipment Structures, Flare Stack Structure, Fired Heaters, HRSG, Boilers, Incinerators, Bio-treaters, Cooling Tower as well as Modular equipment such as Compressors, Pumps, Reactors, Silos, Towers, Exchanges, Loading Arms and quick turn around plant maintenance &nbsp;projects.</span></font></p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt"></span></font>&nbsp;</p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt">We also perform Laser Alignment of Rotating Equipment.</span></font></p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px">&nbsp;</p>  <p style="LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px"><font color="#333333" face="arial"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt">We have clocked more than 5 million man-hours and handled more than 100,000 Ton of Steel Structure and 50,000 Ton of equipment within customer's budget and schedule. We diligently adhere to safety procedure outlined in our established Work Procedure, Method Statement and Job Safety Analysis.</span></font></p>   #NAME?  #NAME?
```

So there are 2 columns are not recognized and put the wrong data :

```
#NAME?  #NAME?
```

Comment: you want to mean i.e you wanna read or import the csv file?

Comment: I mean how could I read (not import) .csv file ? Is there any reader (like excel ?) can read it in the same table format that I see in the result in sql server ?

Comment: so basicall you wan to read a sql table in .csv format using which language .net ,php or what?

Comment: this link surely helps you http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

Comment: I don't need to use any language to read it, just any editor that can view that file will do (like we use notepad, wordpad, word ... to read text file). The link you post is other way around, import .csv into sql server. But I export from sql server to .csv and pass this file to some one else, he doesnot use sql server but he want to use simpler program to view this file and do something on the table.

Comment: I think the problem is because in my data have comma delimited, then using excel it will separate these comma to different columns make data table look like a mess. How to keep it in the right table as I view in sql result ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What does the result look like?  Show us a sample CSV file with 3 or 4 lines of data.

Comment: I edited my question as your request. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, when you saved the CSV file you did so either without any delimiters on the fields or else with a delimiter that was not the double-quote delimiter required by Excel (in this case, most likely single quotes).

Excel requires that any field that itself contains a comma must be enclosed in double quotes, otherwise it cannot tell where each field ends in the file and the results will appear "mixed up" when the file is loaded.

This is only a guess because you did not show us a sample of the CSV file you're having problems loading.  If you were to show even a couple of lines of that file, it might be more obviously to us what's going on.

Additionally, because you did not mention which SQL product and front-end you're using to create the CSV file it's not possible to advise you how to solve the quoting problem (if, indeed, that is the problem).

Comment: Updated my question to make it clearer. Your guess is very close to the reason I think. May be I can change the comma into something else as in my select query now I use: "SELECT ', '+ u.description  from KeySkills u  
INNER JOIN Companies c ON c.companyId = u.companyId  
WHERE c.companyName = c1.companyName   
ORDER BY c.companyName FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS listStr " But I don't think it can solve all the problem as in the data it self has some special character, I can clean these part of the data.

Comment: A couple of things: 1) you didn't mention that you were creating the CSV format yourself.  In that case *you're responsible* for adding the field quotes and doubling-up any quotes inside text.  Better to pull the fields you want and let SSMS create the CSV file.  2) You certainly do have internal commas in your values and thus will need the quoting.

Comment: So how to let SSMS create the CSV file and how do I put the quoting ?

Comment: In SSMS run your query and then right-click on any column header in the results section.  Select Save Results As. . ., select CSV from the drop down, and enter a file name.  The resulting file should be correctly quoted for loading into Excel.

Comment: That is the way I am using, instead of saving the single column, I select the top left corner where it save the whole result table. So I do not creating the CSV format my self right? I am doing exactly what you are mentioning but Excel doesn't load it correctly. What I see in excel is very messy, not as in SSMS.